# How do I make a time lapse in my code so it updates slower?

Tags: xna, 2d, collision-detection, physics

I have made some collision if statements, but they didn't work.

```
            birdbox3.X += 5;
            birdbox3.Y -= 5;

            if (birdbox3.Intersects(Banner1)) {

                birdbox3.Y += 10;

            }
            else if (birdbox3.Intersects(Banner2)) { 

                birdbox3.Y = -birdbox3.Y; }
```

So if we take the first statement, the box is initially on the left down corner.
According to my code, it would ideally be going right+up in my game, once it hits the banner on the extreme top, it should go down+right, thus both the X and the Y positions will increase. But what happens is that is starts bouncing really fast, after debugging I realised it was forever stuck in the first if, it's almost as if it collides 2 times, reverting Y to its initial movement, colliding a 3rd time, and doing the process over and over.

Which brings us to the question, how can I make the Update code run a tad bit slower, or after half a second or such passes, so when it runs, it doesn't misinterpret collisions?

Comment: A drawing of the situation would make things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this somewhere else. Adding a bigger if statement such as this :

```
private int elapsedTime = 0; //Declared at class level

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    elapsedTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

if (elapsedTime > 500)
{
    elapsedTime = 0;
    birdbox3.X += 5;
    birdbox3.Y -= 5;

    if (birdbox3.Intersects(Banner1))
    {
        birdbox3.Y += 10;
    }
    else if (birdbox3.Intersects(Banner2))
    {
        birdbox3.Y = -birdbox3.Y;
    }
}
}
```

easily splits frames apart from each other, which helps with handling such issues, additionally this code sort of goes too far down the Y axis, so it goes further than the banner before it actually tests for it. I hope this helps anyone running into the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure artificially delaying your frame time is a good solution in general, but if there's no visible problems from doing this, it might be good enough in your case.

Comment: a better way to do this is  `birdbox3.X += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 0.5f;` instead.